# ¿Cómo obtener fecha correcta, incluso si se cambia la del sistema?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de gestión contable, facturas, etc... Tengo un problema, y es que necesito que las facturas que guarde en la base de datos se almacenen con la fecha actual, incluso la hora. Pero si uso la fecha del sistema, simplemente cambiando la de Windows también se altera la de mi proyecto. También quiero evitar el uso de internet en lo posible, no necesariamenta

Uso c# y MySql, además la base de datos es local

Gracias de antemano...

Comment: Crea un usuario sin permisos de cambio de fecha en el Windows y se feliz :D

Comment: no se como esperas obtener la hora, si alguien no te la dice ;) siempre puedes verificar que no sea menor a la ultima ingresada

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar `DateTime.Now` en c# o `Currdate`? puedes ponernos lo que has intentado hasta ahora para ayudarte?

Comment: La opción mas segura es obtener la fecha de un servidor NIST, pero para ello necesitas acceso a internet.

Comment: Para trabajar con fechas, la recomendación que te propongo es trabajar siempre con fechas `UTC`. Es un formato de fecha universal. En la estructura de `DateTime` se proporciona métodos para trabajar con dicho tipo de fechas tales como `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` o `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: Además, existe un servicio en Windows denominado `Windows Time service` disponible para `Windows Server 2016`, `Windows Server 2012 R2`, `Windows Server 2012`, `Windows 10` o posteriores y un conjunto de utilidades, `Windows Time Service Tools` cuyo comando es  `w32tm`  con el cual se puede sincronizar la fecha y hora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comenta @gbianchi difícilmente puedes saber la hora de una transacción si no tienes un servidor que te de la hora de referencia.

Una opción puede ser que tus computadoras cliente no tengan salida a Internet, pero puedan comunicarse con un servidor de red local que sea tu referencia hacia Internet.

Te dejo alguna información que te puede servir:

**1. Implementando un servidor NTP que se sincronice con un servidor externo**

Puedes usar un [servidor NTP en Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server), en un [servidor linux](https://www.raulprietofernandez.net/blog/gnu-linux/como-instalar-un-servidor-de-ntp-en-gnu-linux-ubuntu-server) o una computadora con Windows 7 en adelante [activar las característica de servicios TCPIP Simple](http://techgenix.com/windows-7-simple-tcpip-services-what-how/).

Y sincronizarla con el CENAM con su [aplicación SyncCNM](http://www.cenam.mx/hora_oficial/sincronia.aspx) o con el comando [w32tm](https://juliorestrepo.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/ntp-windows-sincronizando-la-hora-del-computador/).

Y apuntar a tu computadoras cliente (las que usan la aplicación) para que sincronicen la hora con el servidor por medio de los [servicios de Windows](https://repositoriotecno.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/configurar-ntp-servidor-horario-en-windows-server-cliente-y-servidor/).**

**2. Obtener desde tu aplicación la fecha y hora por medio del [protocolo DayTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol)**

Ejemplo:

Desde el cmd de Windows ejecuta:

```
telnet time.nist.gov 13
```

En Linux o Windows 18.03 (Spring Creators Update 2018)

```
curl time.nist.gov:13
```

Puedes ver la implementación de un cliente para este protocolo usando socket en Java en las páginas 244-250 del libro [Java Network Programming: Developing Networked Applications](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=cXggAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=nist%20server%20telnet&source=bl&ots=AQU1ORpqK5&sig=cyT0nkj8_0dRBV10UUHcGKcvBj8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBnvSUgd7bAhXVHzQIHde4BuQQ6AEIZzAF#v=onepage&q=nist%20server%20telnet&f=false) no te será difícil implementarlo en C#.

**3. Desde tu aplicación Parsear una página externa que muestre la hora:**

Esta es una opción fácil si ya has parseado otras páginas:

Algunas páginas que puedes parsear:

https://time.is/es/Monterrey

https://time.gov/

Referencias:

[CENAM - Hora oficial en México](http://www.cenam.mx/hora_oficial/Default.aspx)

[Como funciona el servidor NTP Cronos del CENAM](https://tf.nist.gov/sim/Papers/S3E5_Jimenez.pdf)

[NIST Internet Time Service](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/services/internet-time-service-its)